# SunOne obj.conf friendly urls - redirect /index.jsp -> /

Tags: jsp, redirect, friendly-url, sunone

We're old school. We still use SunOne 6.1.

I cannot seem to get anything to register on my local machine when making modifications to the `obj.conf` file on my local machine (windows). Is the behavior different for windows machines then unix machines?

More specifically we are trying to redirect `/index.jsp` pages to the parents folder for more friendly URLS. For example:

`https://cooldomain/awesome/index.jsp` -> `https://cooldomain/awesome/`

Currently you can hit both, which is causing SEO issues as google sees them as two pages with the same content.

Another odd windows/unix item is on the windows machine (developer environment) the url gets forced to index.jsp. For instance if I go to `https://cooldomain/awesome/` it forces me to -> `https://cooldomain/awesome/index.jsp`

I am making simple changes in the OBJ.conf file locally to try and solve the above issue, specifically for testing I am putting in a redirect like so:

`NameTrans fn="redirect" from="/amazing" url="http://domain.com/amazing/feature"`

and it will just pull up `http://domain.com/amazing`

Anyone have insight on this legacy system?

Answer (score 0):

If you hit a nametrans redirect it does it, I think you have to filter out urls that you want to bypass the nametrans....

```
<If $path =~ 'index.jsp'>
  NameTrans fn="redirect" url="http://domain.com/amazing/feature"
</If>
```

So you're only doing the redirect if you hit the index.jsp page.